# Scheme: Combining random and substring

Tags: random, scheme, substring

I am trying to create a procedure that has a user input a non-empty string and then returns a random letter from the input in a substring of length one.

i.e.

```
(pick-at-random "word")

~"w"

(pick-at-random "word")

~"r"
```

So far I've got:

```
    (define pick-at-random
      (lambda (s)
        (substring s (random(string-length s)) ())))
```

This gives me the position of the letter I want to display and I feel like where the () is, I should have some variable representing the start value of the substring and then add one to it. However, I don't know how to do this. Simply put, I am asking how I can limit the substring to length one while using the random function in the start value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `let` to bind the random number to a variable.

```
(define pick-at-random
  (lambda (s)
    (let ((index (random (string-length s))))
      (substring s index (+ index 1)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative answer without using `substring`, in this way you don't need to save the index in a `let` binding. It's a more functional (and hence, idiomatic) solution to the problem:

```
(define (pick-at-random s)          ; read the following lines from bottom to top
  (string                           ; convert single character to string
    (string-ref s                   ; access character in string, given an index
      (random (string-length s))))) ; generate a random valid index in the string

(pick-at-random "word")
> "d"   ; random result
```

The previous procedure generates a random valid index and then picks the character in that position within the string. As the last step, it turns back the single character into a string of length one.

Answer (score 0):

The prior two answers are fine. Alternatively, you could break this problem into two problems:

- Develop the function "nth-char" that accepts a word and an index, and returns a string containing the nth character of the word.
- Develop the function "pick-at-random" that does what you describe.  (Incidentally, I think a name such as "random-char" is somewhat better than "pick-at-random".)

This decomposition solves the problem you describe, by making it an argument to another function.

"Under the hood", this is the same solution as the one that uses "let".